Using the Extra Element Theorem on Bandpass Filter
Below is a bandpass filter which I want to use in a RF circuit and I wanted to design it using the extra element theorem. Below shows my attempt to find the transfer function of the input impedance of the network.
I included the input impedance of the circuit connected at the output of the filter. I don't think my final answer is correct, since this is a 4th order circuit and the denominator of the transfer function is of 3rd degree. All the time constants and gains were calculated when putting the components in their DC state. For the transfer function H(s), Rd was factored out of the denominator and numerator and the limit as Rd went to infinity was taken.
What did I do wrong?



Well, I get a numerator with only a 2nd order s term and a denominator of 4th order. solve(Eq(vout/zl+vout/(s*l4)+vout*s*c3+vout/(s*l1+1/s/c2),vin/(s*l1+1/s/c2)),vout)[0]/vin = c2*l4*s**2*zl/(c2*c3*l1*l4*s**4*zl + c2*l1*l4*s**3 + c2*l1*s**2*zl + c2*l4*s**2*zl + c3*l4*s**2*zl + l4*s + zl).

Why not use a "step-up" low-pass L-pad followed by a "step-down" high-pass L-pad. This keeps input and output impedance the same at the frequency of interest and is easy-ish to solve.

You have assumed the problem right.This is a 4th order circuit. So,the degree of the denominator in the transfer function must be 4. But in the final expression in your handwritten math, the denominator seems to be a 3rd degree polynomial.The denominator should have an additional term to account for the full fourth-order dynamics. Please recheck the time constants. Here is a bandpass filter tutorial that you can see for reference: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/2_4GHz_Hairpin_Bandpass_Filter_0b6b3acf.html

Here is what I found with Maple.
Did not use FACTs, sorry.


